# Azure Hortonworks CloudBreak hosts file not correct

Tags: azure, hadoop, networking, docker, hortonworks-data-platform

I have created a cluster using the [CloudBreak](http://cloudbreak.sequenceiq.com) and that all works and I can log into the servers just fine. The problem that I am having is the network setups on the host os and the docker containers seems to not be setup right. The host os and the containers /etc/hosts file like like this

```
cloudbreak# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

This causes a problem for the hadoop cluster because all the nodes then don’t know how to communicate. If I change the hosts files to contain the other nodes then things start to work. However this does not seems like something I should have to do. This will also be a problem when trying make new clusters, as I will have to go in and make changes, and the auto scaling will not work if i have to change the host file on every host and docker container.

Any help would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudBreak does not use the host file to resolve the other nodes in the cluster, It uses [swarm and consul](http://sequenceiq.com/cloudbreak-docs/latest/architecture/) for discovery.